# Get the filename of the latest file created

Tags: bash, file

I was wondering if it's possible to get the filename of the latest file created on a directory but checking if such filename was created after certain time

Not sure if there is a command I could use to get first to get the strictly latest filename created and then the time of creation to compare with certain time

OS: Ubuntu/Linux

Comment: `ls -t | tail -1` will print the newest file.

Comment: Note that this uses the modification time. Must Unix filesystems don't store creation time.

Comment: I thought that this could be more doable, but the second part, is the one that is generating  more conflict

Comment: 1st: determine if your filesystem maintains file creation (aka `birth`) dates (eg, does the output of `stat filename` show a datetime stamp labeled `Birth`?); 2nd: if you do see `Birth`, and you can confirm that `Birth` == creation, then consider converting all datetimes (file/Birth, the cutoff) to seconds since epoch (eg, `stat -c '%W - %n'`) and then ... 3rd: sort the list by epoch seconds and pick the largest/max epoch that's greater than the cutoff epoch

Comment: what do you mean by `generating more conflict`?

Comment: You did not specify the operating system you are using. FWIK, Windows and MacOS store the creation time. If you are on Unix or Linux, define what you mean by creation time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution I've come up with thanks to some comments, comparing with 22h/10pm

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=$(ls -tr | tail -1)

FILECREATEDATE=$(stat -c %Y "$FILENAME")
TODAY22H=$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-%d) 22:00:00" +%s)

if (( FILECREATEDATE >= TODAY22H )); then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

Still, I would prefer an option with `find` instead of `ls` because it handles better non-alphanumeric filenames (maybe it's not possible, so I will stick to ls)

`find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1`

But I see the time in front of the file name (which is used for sorting)

Comment: There is nothing in your code, which would query a creation date.  `%Y` queries the modification time (as number of seconds since epoch). For instance, every time one performs a `touch` on that file, the modification time would be updated.

Comment: Perhaps queriying the inode change time (`%Z`) would make more sense? It is not influenced by a `touch` command.

Comment: @user1934428 But it's influenced by things like `chmod`, which are even less like creation. For many purposes, modification is what they actually want, since it's effectively creating a new version of the file. And using `touch` is intended to make it seem like a new version was created.

Comment: @Barmar: How can a _chmod_  influence the inode change time? It does not reallocate a file to a different place, does it? IMO, the question itself is a bit unclear. The OP should have stated from the start, that he is interested in the modification time of the file, which indeed is often good enough for practical purpose. One problem I experienced in Windows was, that on certain conditions, files on a network share got the modification time updated, if they were opened for reading. The OP is using WSL - maybe he is facing a similar problem?

Comment: @user1934428 Permissions are stored in the inode, so changing them changes the inode and updates the time. Try it and see.

Comment: @Barmar: I tried, but did not see. However I'm on MacOS. Could it be that BSD is handling this differently from Linux?

Comment: @user1934428 I'm on MacOS. I just did `ls -lc .bashrc;chmod 700 .bashrc;ls -lc .bashrc`. The ctime changed.

Comment: @user1934428 Oh, just noticed that you're talking about a network share. If the server isn't a Unix-like OS, it may do things differently.

Comment: @Barmar: I did nearly the same, but checked the time using `stat -f %Sm FILENAME`, and did not see an update of the timestamp. It's not a network share. Could it be due to a difference between `stat` and `ls`?

Comment: `%Sm` shows the modification time, not the inode change time. @user1934428 Try `%Sc` to see the ctime.

Comment: If you don't want to see the inode change time in front of the result, add this | cut -f2- -d" " at the end of your command.

Comment: @Barmar: You convinced me!